# Matlab function to Python

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I know these are the questions I'm asking from months now, but I still have problems:

Matlab:

```
gy=tanh(alpha.*xup.'*w)
```

This is how I translated it to Python:

```
GY = np.tanh(np.multiply(np.multiply(Alpha, np.transpose(XUp)), WSeg)
```

It looks correct, except for the fact that GY is different from Matlab to Python.
In Matlab - with sz = size(gy) - it says:

```
sz =

 1     2
```

In Python - with print(GY.shape) - it says:

```
(2, 128)
```

what's wrong ?
I can assure you that the variables used match perfectly since this point.

Comment: In `(alpha.*xup.')*w`, the multiplication on the right is not the corresponding position multiplication but the matrix multiplication.

Comment: Try `np.tanh((Alpha * np.transpose(XUp)) @ WSeg)`

Comment: Ok, now I understood what you were saying. Basically, this is the operation I'm supposed to do: `GY = np.tanh(np.matmul(np.multiply(Alpha, np.transpose(XUp)), WSeg))`, which is the same operation the @Cris said. The problem is that this doesn't work either. `ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 2 is different from 128)`.

Comment: It would be nice to know the shapes of all the inputs, i.e. `Alpha`, `XUp` and `WSeg`.

Comment: Please read [mre]. The operation I gave you is a direct translation of the MATLAB code, but the arrays must have the right sizes for that to work. Also, I don't understand why you want to use `np.multiply` over `*` and `np.matmul` over `@`. It just becomes harder to read the code.

Comment: No real reason actually, I just already used those and so I kept using. BTW I found out what the problem is: XUp is 1D vector, and therefore transpose doesn't work. So now I'm trying to have it turn into a 2D 1x128 vector. Then it should work.

Comment: Ah, and BTW, don't know how is it even possible, but to make it work it is WSeg that must be trasposed, not XUp.

`XUp is 1x128`
`WSeg is 2x128`

To make `GY 1x2`, the product must be: `(1, 128) * (128, 2)`

Comment: `np.tanh((Alpha * XUp) @ WSeg.T)` ?

Comment: would you please be so kind to supply all input values, for both MATLAB 'tanh' and PYTHON 'tanh' , the values you have used.

Comment: @norok2 yes, I did it so, except I used numpy functions (no reason, I just felt to): `GY = np.tanh(np.matmul(np.multiply(Alpha, XUp), np.transpose(WSeg)))`. @John BG, it would be too long as they are split across various functions and it would be a pain for you to read. BTW the problem is solved I think.

Answer (score 0):

This MATLAB code

```
n = 3;
m = 4;
k = 5;
alpha = (1 + 2i) * ones(n, m);
xup  = (3 + 4i) * ones(m, n);
w = (5 + 6i) * ones(m, k);
alpha.*xup.'*w
```

````
ans =

  -340 +  80i  -340 +  80i  -340 +  80i  -340 +  80i  -340 +  80i
  -340 +  80i  -340 +  80i  -340 +  80i  -340 +  80i  -340 +  80i
  -340 +  80i  -340 +  80i  -340 +  80i  -340 +  80i  -340 +  80i```
````

does the same as this python code

```
import numpy as np
n = 3
m = 4
k = 5
alpha = np.full((n, m), 1 + 2j)
xup  = np.full((m, n), 3 + 4j)
w = np.full((m, k),  5 + 6j) 
print(alpha * xup.T @ w)
```

```
[[-340.+80.j -340.+80.j -340.+80.j -340.+80.j -340.+80.j]
 [-340.+80.j -340.+80.j -340.+80.j -340.+80.j -340.+80.j]
 [-340.+80.j -340.+80.j -340.+80.j -340.+80.j -340.+80.j]]
```

Note that `alpha.*xup.'` and `alpha * xup.T` are elementwise multiplications.

Comment: `(3 + 4j) * np.ones((m, n))` -> `np.full((m, n), 3 + 4j)`

Comment: `np.matmul(alpha * np.transpose(xup), w)` -> `(alpha * xup.T) @ w`

Comment: Those are just aesthetics though. Functionally, your way works just the same.